# Calculating the perimeter of my object given another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how I can calculate the perimeter of my object called 'Rectangle' if I do not have the x-coordinates and y-coordinates saved in the Rectangle class.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, xcoord=0, ycoord=0):
        self.x = xcoord
        self.y = ycoord

    def setx(self, xcoord):
        self.x = xcoord

    def sety(self, ycoord):
        self.y = ycoord

    def get(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, bottom_left, top_right, colour):
        self.bottom_left = bottom_left
        self.top_right = top_right
        self.colour = colour

    def get_colour(self):
        return self.colour

    def get_bottom_left(self):
        return self.bottom_left

    def get_top_right(self):
        return self.top_right

    def reset_colour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour

    def move(self,dx,dy):
        Point.move(self.bottom_left,dx,dy)
        Point.move(self.top_right,dx,dy)

    def get_perimeter(self):
```

I am calling the function in python shell in the following format

```
r1=Rectangle(Point(),Point(1,1),'red')
r1.get_perimeter()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more basic geometry than Python.

Since you only provide bottom left and top right points I'm assuming that the rectangle has sides parallel to x/y axis. In that case:

```
def get_perimeter(self):
    return 2*(abs(self.top_right.x-self.bottom_left.x)+abs(self.bottom_left.y-self.top_right.y))
```

I've put the `abs` function for good measure because left & right, top & bottom doesn't presuppose of the orientation of the coordinate system.

Note: you *have* `x` and `y` of the 2 defining points "saved" (accessible) in your `Rectangle` class, not directly as a direct member, but as a member of a member.

Comment: How can I use .x since its not in the rectangle class.

Comment: Is it because I can use any method defined in any class if they are all in the same file? Therefore I can use any variable of any class.

Comment: you can access `x` through the `Point` object which has an `x` member. And you have 2 `Point` objects in your `Rectangle` class.

Comment: So it works as if self is the rectangle object. The rectangle object has a variable called bottom_left. the bottom_left variable is assigned the Point object. The Point object has an x variable and a y variable. That is why Rectangle can access it right? is it like a hierarchy where variable x is at the bottom and the class of Rectangle is at the top?

Comment: you got it right. And variable `x` being an integer (or float) it's not an object per se, but a "leaf" of the hierarchy tree.

Comment: Thank you so much Jean-François.